# how to use ember simple auth without ember cli or AMD

Tags: authentication, ember.js

we are re-writing our web application in ember.js. we use our rest api and the api uses oAuth 2.0 authentication system. Now, we are trying to use ember simple auth https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth and we also tried to use https://github.com/Vestorly/torii but it seems both needs to have AMD loader or ember cli. Unfortunately we are not using any of them. I would like to know what people using for authentication for oAuth2.0. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
I downloaded ember simple auth 0.7.0 from distribution. But how do I configure with my ember application. I tried use it like this; But it didn't work.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
    name:       'authentication',
    after:      'simple-auth',
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        var applicationRoute = container.lookup('route:application');
        var session          = container.lookup('simple-auth-session:main');
        // handle the session events
        session.on('sessionAuthenticationSucceeded', function() {
            applicationRoute.transitionTo('index');
        });
    }
});
var ApplicationRouteMixin = requireModule('simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin')['default'];
```

in my route like this:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin, {});
```

@marcoow do you have any example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Simple Auth also has a distribution that exports a global (`SimpleAuth`) - download here: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/releases/tag/0.7.0

You should really use Ember CLI of course though...

Comment: can you please provide an example using ember simple auth without ember cli

Comment: Check the examples in the github repo

Comment: can you please give me the link.

Comment: The Link above goes to the repo - examples folder is in the project root

Comment: Is it this example https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/1-simple.html ? I am really having hard time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, you can take that one as a reference m